# On click of item in for loop show other element in for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What I have is a for loop that shows podcast items.
Each podcast item has a iframe with a Spotify embed. When you click on the podcast item, the podcast item should go invisible and the Spotify embed should pop up.
I can kind of do this in css by using:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
}

.podcast_item:active ~ iframe {
    display: block;
}

.podcast_item:active {
    display: none;
}
```

But when I do this, because of doing the active, it really bugs, because the spotify embed doesn't stay visible.
My question is, how do I achieve this by using Javascript?

Code for the podcast item and spotify embed:

```
<div
  v-for="(podcast, index) in content.podcasts"
  :key="index"
  class="swiper-slide"
>
  <PodcastsItem
    :imageUrl="podcast.image"
    :title="podcast.name
    :text="'Duur: ' + podcast.id + ' ms'"
    class="podcast_item"
  />
  <iframe
    style="border-radius:12px"
    :src="
    'https://open.spotify.com/embed/episode/' + podcast.id + '?utm_source=generator'"
    width="100%"
    height="232"
    frameBorder="0"
    allowfullscreen=""
    allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

What I have right now:
Each postcast item has a spotify embed under it that is invisible

Expected result:
When you click on a podcast item, the right iframe shows up under the podcast item, for example if you click the second podcast item, the second spotify embed shows up.

Comment: Because you use vue: Wouldn't it be better to use v-if to show/hide elements? Another way is to use one iframe and change the src instead of multiple iframes.

Comment: Oh wow, that is indeed a great idea. Never thought of it because this is actually my first time using Vue haha. Thank you very much!

If anyone else knows how to do it with Javascript, it will be also very helpful for other projects for me :)